# Cycle structures of $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

A problem from my algebra homework requests the following:

> List all the possible cycle structures in $S_6$. For each cycle structure, compute the  order of an element with that cycle structure.

I'm almost certain that this material has not been covered in class, and that its appearance in this homework is a misprint; but regardless I would like to learn how to solve the problem.

I understand that "cycle structure" refers to how a permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of disjoint $k_i$-cycles, where $\sum_i k_i = n$, and that conjugate permutations have identical cycle structure. I know Lagrange's theorem, but I'm not sure how this could help me enumerate all the possible cycle structures.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe this problem is much easier than I thought. Do you just partition 6 into non-negative unordered integers, then come up with a corresponding cycle structure for each such partition?

Comment: Yes, that is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Denote  $1^{n_1}2^{n_2}\dotsm 6^{n_6}$ by a permutation in $S_6$ which have a disjoint cycle structure (i.e. it is a product of disjoint $n_1$ $1$-cycles, $n_2$ $2$-cycles,$\dotsc,n_6$ $6$-cycles) i.e. $(123)(4)(5)(6)$ denoted as $1^3 3^1$ and $(1)(23)(456)$ is denoted as $1^1 2^1 3^1$. Note that the order of a permutation in the disjoint cycle structure is the l.c.m. of the order of its components and the order of a $k$-cycle is $k$. So the possible cycle structure of a permutation in $S_6$ are:

$1^6$

$1^4 2^1,1^2 2^2, 2^3$

$1^3 3^1,1^1 2^1 3^1, 3^2$

$1^2 4^1,2^1 4^1$

$1^1 5^1$

$6^1.$

So the possible orders of a permutation in $S_6$ are $1,2,3,4,5,6$.